# What is the purpose of an import in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, state, infrastructure-as-code, hcl

This question is **not** *how* to import and it's not *what's the purpose of tfstate*. It's what's the purpose of importing a pre-existing resource, esp. compared to just referencing the ID of the existing resource?

Terraform has [the feature of `terraform import`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html). HashiCorp describes the purpose of this as:

> Terraform is able to import existing infrastructure. This allows you take resources you've created by some other means and ***bring it under Terraform management***.

> This is a great way to slowly transition infrastructure to Terraform, or to be able to be confident that you can use Terraform in the future if it potentially doesn't support every feature you need today.

I read [the article about the purpose of Terraform state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/purpose.html). It does make sense to me to track Terraform state with `.tfstate` files when those files are mappings back to the configurations in `.tf` files.

But it's still unclear to me what the purpose of a standalone `.tfstate` file is when it only maps to an empty resource block. If there is a resource not in terraform yet, I would typically do one of two things:

1. put the resource in terraform, tear down the resource manually and re-deploy the resource with terraform, or...
2. keep the resource un-templated, reference its resource ID as a parameter and get its metadata via a data element for terraform-managed resources that rely on it.
3. Is `terraform import` an alternative to those two approaches? And if so, why would you use that approach?

The only way to make changes to an imported resource (that only has an empty resource block in the `.tf` file and detailed state in `.tfstate) is to make manual changes and then re-import into` .tfstate`, right? And if so, then what's the point of tracking the state of that resource in terraform?

I'm sure there's a good reasons. Just want to understand this deeper! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it's still unclear to me what the purpose of a standalone .tfstate
> file is when it only maps to an empty resource block.

You wouldn't use a standalone .tfstate file. You would be using the same .tfstate file that all your other resources are in.

> If there is a resource not in terraform yet, I would typically do one
> of two things:
>
> 1. put the resource in terraform, tear down the resource manually and re-deploy the resource with terraform, or...
> 2. keep the resource un-templated, reference its resource ID as a parameter and get its metadata via a data element for
>    terraform-managed resources that rely on it.
>
> Is terraform import an alternative to those two approaches? And if so,
> why would you use that approach?

Consider the case where you have a production database with terrabytes of data already load in it, and users actively performing actions that query that database 24 hours a day. Your option `1` would require some down time, possibly a lot of down time, because you would have to deal with backing up and restoring terrabytes of data. Your option `2` would never let you manage changes to your database server via Terraform. That's what the Terraform import feature solves. It lets Terraform take "full control" of resources that already exist, without having to recreate them.

I agree that if a system outage is not an issue, and if recreating a resource isn't going to take much time, using option `1` is the way to go. Option `2` is only for resources that you never want to fully manage in Terraform, which is really a separate issue from the one Terraform import solves.

Answer (score 1):

When importing a resource with `terraform import` it is necessary to write the configuration block to manage it with Terraform. On the [same page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html#currently-state-only) you linked it states:

> The current implementation of Terraform import can only import resources into the state. It does not generate configuration. A future version of Terraform will also generate configuration.
>
> Because of this, prior to running terraform import it is necessary to
> write manually a resource configuration block for the resource, to
> which the imported object will be mapped.

So to bring preexisting resources under Terraform management, you ***first*** write the resource block for it in a `.tf` file. Next you use `terraform import` to map the resource to this resource block in your `.tfstate`. The next time you run `terraform plan`, Terraform will determine what changes (if any) will need to be made upon the next `terraform apply` based on the resource block and the actual state of the resource.

**EDIT**

The "why" of `terraform import` is to manage resources that are previously unknown to Terraform. As you alluded to in your second bullet point, if you want metadata from a resource but ***do not want to change the configuration of the resource***, you would use a `data` block and reference that in dependent resources.

When you want to manage the configuration of a resource that was provisioned outside of Terraform you use `terraform import`. If you tear down the resource there may be data loss or service downtime until you re-deploy with Terraform, but if you use `terraform import` the resource will be preserved.

The import process can be started with an empty `resource` block, but the attributes need to be filled out to describe the resource. You will get the benefits of `terraform plan` after importing, which can help you find the discrepancies between the `resource` block and the actual state of the resource. Once the two match up, you can continue to make additional changes to the resource like any other resource in Terraform.

Comment: I understand *how* to use an imported resource (by writing an empty resource block for it in a .tf file). My question is *why* would you use it. I just edited my question a bit more to highlight that.

"The next time you run `terraform plan`, Terraform will determine what changes will need to be made."

Are you saying that although an imported resource starts off with an empty resource block, you can then start adding properties to the block, thereby making all post-import changes to that resource via Terraform and getting all the benefits of `terraform plan` when making those changes?

Comment: I made an edit to try to address your comment, does it help? @YannStoneman

Comment: Spot on! Your example use-case of `terraform import` is super helpful: after import, fill out the attributes of the empty block, run plan to see the diff with the actual state of the resource, edit and repeat until they match up, and then start treating the resource like any other in Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform `state file` is your source of truth for your cloud infrastructure. Terraform uses local state to create plans and make changes to the infrastructure. Before any terraform operation, terraform does a `refresh` to update the state with the `real` infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the benefit of the `.tfstate` file and how it helps with `terraform plan`. I revised the question to be more clear.